# Why do I get ValueError : math domain error?

Tags: python

I wrote a function named `analyze_the_shape` that takes a list of 2D vertices such that the list is in the order of a clockwise traversal of the vertices in the 2D Euclidean space.

I call it in the interpreter and give `[(0, 0), (0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 0)]` as input but I get `ValueError : math domain error`. I expect to see `return ["SQUARE", 4.0]`. What can I do ?

```
import math

def analyze_the_shape(liste):
    if len(liste) == 2 :
        d = ( (liste[1][0] - liste[0][0])**2 + (liste[1][1] - liste[0][1])**2 )**(0.5)   
        return ["LINESEGMENT", d ] 
    if len(liste) == 4 :
        d1 = abs(( (liste[1][0] - liste[0][0])**2 + (liste[1][1] - liste[0][1])**2 )**(0.5))
        d2 = abs(( (liste[2][0] - liste[1][0])**2 + (liste[2][1] - liste[1][1])**2 )**(0.5))
        d3 = abs(( (liste[3][0] - liste[2][0])**2 + (liste[3][1] - liste[2][1])**2 )**(0.5))
        d4 = abs(( (liste[0][0] - liste[3][0])**2 + (liste[0][1] - liste[3][1])**2 )**(0.5)) 
        hypo = abs(( (liste[2][1] - liste[0][1])**2 + (liste[2][0] - liste[0][0])**2 )**(0.5))
        cos_angle = float((hypo**2 - (d3)**2 + (d4)**2) / ((-2.0)*(d4)*(d3)))
        angle = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_angle))
        if d1 == d2 == d3 == d4 and abs(angle - 90.0) < 0.001 :
            return ["SQUARE", d1]
```

This is the error I get:

```
>>> import a
>>> a.analyze_the_shape([(0, 0), (0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 0)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "a.py", line 15, in analyze_the_shape

ValueError: math domain error
```

Answer (score 9):

This exception means that `cos_angle` is not a valid parameter for `math.acos`.

Specifically, in this example, it is just below -1, which is out of `acos` definition.

You could probably try to force your returned `cos_angle` within `[-1,1]` with something like :

```
def clean_cos(cos_angle):
    return min(1,max(cos_angle,-1))
```

However, this will not return `SQUARE`, since `cos_angle` is more or less equals to `-1` in your example, and `angle` thus equals `180`. There is probably an issue with your computation before the exception.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it turns out @crld is right. 
My input values are supposed to be in the range [-1, 1], but...

```
print('{0:.32f}'.format(x))
>> 1.00000000000000022204460492503131
```

So, as a general rule, I suggest rounding all the floats you feed into `math.acos`.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, the stack trace I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "md.py", line 22, in <module>
    analyze_the_shape([(0, 0), (0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 0)])
  File "md.py", line 18, in analyze_the_shape
    angle = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_angle))
ValueError: math domain error
```

I know `math.acos` only accepts values such that `-1.0 <= x <= 1.0`.  If I print out `cos_angle < -1.0` right before the line `angle = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_angle))`, it prints `True`.  If I print out `cos_angle`, it prints `-1.0`.

I'm guessing the issue here is that the way Python stores `cos_angle` isn't perfect, and that the value you generate for `cos_angle` is just barely less than `-1.0`.

Perhaps it would be better, if, instead of checking `abs(angle - 90.0) < 0.001`, you checked if `abs(cos_angle) < 0.001`.

**Edit**:

I think you have an error in this line:

```
cos_angle = float((hypo**2 - (d3)**2 + (d4)**2) / ((-2.0)*(d4)*(d3)))
```

It probably should be:

```
cos_angle = float((hypo**2 - ((d3)**2 + (d4)**2)) / ((-2.0)*(d4)*(d3)))
```

Note the extra parens around `(d3)**2 + (d4)**2`.  This makes sure that addition is done *before* you subtract that quantity from `hypo**2`.

Comment: `abs(angle - 90.0) < 0.001` and `abs(cos_angle + 1) < 0.001` do not mean the same. If `angle=90`, `cos_angle=0`. If `cos_angle=-1`, `angle=180`.

Comment: Good catch!  I think there's an error where the OP sets `cos_angle` -- I've pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: "the way Python stores `cos_angle` isn't perfect". This should the "the way floating point numbers are represented on a computer is not perfect, and thus computational errors are unavoidable". Python has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try rounding cos_angle. I had this same problem; in my script the value for x in         `math.acos(x)` came out to -1.0000000000000002. To fix it I just rounded the value for x to six decimal places so it came out to -1.0.